# CakePHP extending controllers (only)

Tags: cakephp, logic

I am building a website based on widgets. I have a general WidgetInstancesController class with several methods, a model and some views for it. Now, I want to know if it's possible to extend this class. In other words, each widget should be another class, extending the WidgetInstancesController class. I want to store these widgets classes under `app/widgets/`. Also, these widgets won't have any specific model (as they will use the parent WidgetInstance model) but may have some specific views.

Any suggestions on how can I do this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can extend without a problem but as far as I know, controllers need to be in /app/controllers. You might want to think about have your widgets as helpers or components

Comment: Helpers surely not, because I need to overwrite controller data. Components...I don't know, it will be too much to load dozens of components per request (it depends on how many widgets the user has active). Or maybe create a folder with the widgets in `app/controllers/widgets/` and simply extend the parent class (WidgetInstancesControllers)? But also, how will I load or call an action from a widget's controller? And will it be able to access model data from the class which it is extending?

Comment: Well the components can be loaded on a 'as needed' case to keep it all light. You'll be able to access the model since you get an instance of the controller that is calling you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest building them as components, but it can be done in other ways.

I have had to do something similar where I built a CMS with add-on modules. To make it work logically, I had to turn MVC on its head a little and go for a *very* thin controller. Essentially, the front-end module logic was contained entirely at the Model level, with the associated views as elements. A module helper fetched and displayed the module in the public front-end. The back-end was handled conventionally via MVC with a normal fatness controller.

As it turned out, the Models were surprisingly lightweight and having everything as elements made usability a dream.

Comment: I am rather new to MVC, so can you explain a little bit how would a widget act if it were a component? From what I understood so far, a component adds extra methods to the current controller, right? If I,for example,need to extend method abc() of the parent controller in the component,how will I do that? Also,will I be able to use **only** the component method and not the controller one? And if I want to personalize a view for each widget,how should I do that and where should I place it? Or,instead of a view, you suggest making a helper? I am a bit confused, will appreciate any further help :)

Comment: I read now about plugins. Will they work for my case? Or are they too much just for overwriting several controller methods? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The introduction page for components says it all, really: http://book.cakephp.org/view/994/Introduction you're not really adding methods to a controller, you're making another class available to use within the controller. It's a convenient way of re-using self-contained chunks of logic elsewhere in the same or different applications. I personally never use plugins as I find they are cumbersome, rarely work as I expect and can interfere with other aspects of an application.